# not able to make the request using urllib using google VM

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, urllib

I am trying to scrape the data from this 'https://www.societe.com' website using the google VM instance, I am getting **request timeout error** for this particular website, I am using same code in my system it's working perfectly fine can anyone help, while launching  VM instance in Google-cloud allowed both HTTP and https in firewall setting

```
import urllib.request as urllib2
master_link='https://www.societe.com'
urllib2.urlopen(master_link)
```

Comment: i am facing the same problem with the AWS also